# Debugging test sfPHPUnit Symfony1.4

Tags: debugging, phpunit, symfony-1.4, functional-testing

Hey sorry if this question is too specific but Im having to refactor some legacy Symfony1.4 code and I can't work out how to dump the response of a get request in a test, to aid debugging a strange error.

The test in question looks like this:

```
public function testDataset () {
$browser = $this->getBrowser();
$browser->
get('/search/dataset')->
with('request')->begin()->
isParameter('module', 'search')->
isParameter('action', 'dataset')->
end()->
with('response')->begin()->
isStatusCode(200)->
checkElement('body', '/Choose your dataset/')->
checkElement('#compareBy', '/High-density residental/')->
checkElement('#compareBy', '/Medium-density residential/')->
checkElement('#compareBy', '/Low-density residential/')->
checkElement('#compareBy', '/Commercial/')->
checkElement('#compareBy', '/CBD/')->
checkElement('#compareBy', '/Heavy industrial/')->
checkElement('#compareBy', '/Light industrial/')->
checkElement('#compareBy', '/Highway \/ Motorway/')->
checkElement('#compareBy', '/Arterial roads/')->
checkElement('#compareBy', '/Local roads/')->
checkElement('#compareBy', '/Open space/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/All New Zealand/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/All North Island/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/All South Island/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Northland/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Auckland/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Waikato/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Bay of Plenty/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Taranaki/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Gisborne/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Hawkes Bay/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Manawatu-Wanganui/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Wellington/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Nelson/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Tasman/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Marlborough/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/West Coast/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Canterbury/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Otago/')->
checkElement('#dataLocation','/Southland/')->
checkElement('#waterTypes','/All stormwater/')->
checkElement('#waterTypes','/Untreated stormwater/')->
checkElement('#waterTypes','/Treated stormwater/')->
checkElement('#waterTypes','/Urban streams/')->
checkElement('#waterTypes','/All water types/')->
checkElement('#flowType','/Storm event/')->
checkElement('#flowType','/Baseflow/')->
end();
}
```

And its failing with:

```
functional_frontend_searchActionsTest::testDataset
response selector "#compareBy" matches regex "/High-density residental/"
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

The page loads fine but I don't know how to actually dump the page response body in the test to investigate what the test is seeing.
Ive tried $browser->getContent(), $browser->getResponse(), $browser->getBody()..

This is fairly trivial in phpunit / Symfony2 and Im sure there is a way to do this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `debug` method on the `sfWebResponse` object. as example:

```
$browser->with('response')->debug();
```

You can check in the [legacy doc here](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/09?orm=Doctrine):

> **Debugging Functional Tests**
>
> Sometimes a functional test fails. As symfony simulates a browser
>   without any graphical interface, it can be hard to diagnose the
>   problem. Thankfully, symfony provides the `debug()` method to output
>   the response header and content:
>
> `$browser->with('response')->debug();`
>
> **The debug() method can be inserted anywhere in a response tester block
>   and will halt the script execution.**

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you thats prefect. I also found you can use "print_r( $browser->getResponse()->getContent() );die;" to dump the response.